# Crystal Report Error : File Could not be found "TableName", at file Location:"TableName"

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, crystal-reports, vb6

I am Using Vb6 and Seagate Crystal Report 8.0 i am trying to export excel directly by coding

> Reports = C:\Sample_Report.rpt
>   Database = C:\Sample.mdb
>   Exe = C:\Sample.exe

to be easy i use the following code

```
Crt1.ReportFileName = "C:\Sample_Report.rpt"
Crt1.SelectionFormula = ""
Crt1.DiscardSavedData = True
crReport.ExportOptions.DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile
Crt1.Destination = crptToFile
Crt1.PrintFileType = crEFTExcel80Tabular
Crt1.PrintFileName = "C:\REPORT.XLS"
Crt1.Action = 1
```

I GOT exported to excel file but heading and title are not exporting and column width not taking details

to overcome this i search and got the following code

```
Private Sub Report_ExportToExcel(ReportPath)
On Error GoTo Loc
Dim a
Dim path1
 path1 = Save_Dialog    '///open save dialog and get path to 

save excel file
If path1 = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim appl As New CRAXDRT.Application
    Dim dbTable As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable
    Dim rep As CRAXDRT.Report
    Set rep = appl.OpenReport("C:\Sample_Report.rpt", 1)

    rep.DiscardSavedData

     For a = 1 To rep.Database.Tables.Count
        rep.Database.Tables(a).Location = "C:\Sample.mdb"
       rep.Database.Tables(a).SetLogOnInfo "C:\Sample.mdb", "Sample.mdb" 
    Next

    rep.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = path1 
    rep.ExportOptions.DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile
    rep.ExportOptions.ExcelAreaType = crDetail
    rep.ExportOptions.ExcelUseTabularFormat = True
    rep.ExportOptions.ExcelTabHasColumnHeadings = True
    rep.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTExcel80Tabular 
    rep.Export False

Exit Sub
Loc:
 MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

From This "Report_ExportToExcel" Code i got my actual output

i have another set of code for Preview of crystal Report, i am using this for whole project

```
Private sub Preview()
Crt1.ReportFileName ="C:\Sample_Report.rpt"
Crt1.SelectionFormula = ""
Crt1.DiscardSavedData = True
Crt1.WindowState = crptMaximized
Crt1.Action = 1
End Sub
```

Now i have export and preview separately with different code

i can run the code "Report_ExportToExcel(ReportPath)" as many times i want and i can run preview, there is no error

but

after run the preview code, i get error while running "Report_ExportToExcel(ReportPath)" code

i get error as i attached in the image

[image]

here Callvisitreport is TableName
i have 300+ report developed in this version so i couldn't change to another version
Please someone help to solve this error
thanks in advance

Comment: check whether the report is available at the location where application is searching

Comment: thanks for reply,  Both are in the same location, its pointed correctly, when using export then preview works fine but when using preview then export, Export not working